# почему возникает ошибка class ... not found

Tags: yii2

есть такое дополнение `ratacibernetica/yii2-node-socket` в нем есть такой класс

```
namespace YiiNodeSocket\Assets;

use Yii;
use yii\web\AssetBundle;

/**
 * @author Woody <Woody@HandBid.com>
 * @since 1.0
 */
class NodeSocketAssets extends AssetBundle
```

пытался его подключить и так

`\YiiNodeSocket\Assets\NodeSocketAssets::register($this);` и так

```
use YiiNodeSocket\Assets\NodeSocketAssets;

$nodeSocketAssets= new NodeSocketAssets;

$nodeSocketAssets::register($this);
```

пишет одинаковую ошибку Class 'YiiNodeSocket\Assets\NodeSocketAssets' not found почему не подскажите

Comment: Возможно в этом пакете кривой composer.json. проверьте что директория с расширением указана в файлах `vendor/composer/autoload_*.php`

Comment: @MaxTimakov вот 'YiiNodeSocket\\' => array($vendorDir . '/ratacibernetica/yii2-node-socket/lib/php'),

Comment: посмотрел [репозиторий проекта](https://github.com/ratacibernetica/yii2-node-socket) там директория `assets` с маленькой буквы начинается, а `namespace Assets` - с большой. Возможно проблема в этом

Comment: @MaxTimakov в качестве бреда исправил namespase получил теперь вот такую ошибку Setting unknown property: YiiNodeSocket\NodeSocket::dbOptions

Comment: судя по [коду](https://github.com/ratacibernetica/yii2-node-socket/blob/master/lib/php/NodeSocket.php#L96) там действительно нет `dbOptions` а есть `dbConfiguration`

Comment: @MaxTimakov блин и чего делать переименовывать ?

Comment: по логике надо заменить все вхождения `dbOptions` на `dbConfiguration`, но я могу ошибаться - не смотрел код путью.

Comment: А так этот пакет является форком [oncesk/yii-node-socket](https://github.com/oncesk/yii-node-socket). Может быть стоит указать в зависимостях оригинал?

Comment: @MaxTimakov большое спасибо вам за название пакета все получилось с новым пакетом. Пишите ответ подтвержу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пакет [ratacibernetica/yii2-node-socket](https://github.com/ratacibernetica/yii2-node-socket) является форком [oncesk/yii-node-socket](https://github.com/oncesk/yii-node-socket)

Может быть стоит указать в зависимостях оригинал?